# Square Bracket Syntax

Tags: flash, actionscript

I just started programming flash/actionscript and I am confused as to what the meaning of the square brackets inside classes mean. I appreciate this might answered before but searching for square brackets actionscript yields 0 useful results.

Here are some examples

```
public class FlxGame extends Sprite
{

    //Flex v3.x SDK only (see note above):
    [Embed(source="data/nokiafc22.ttf",fontFamily="system")] protected var junk:String;
```

or inside a package:

```
package
{
    import org.flixel.*;

    [SWF(width = "640", height = "480", backgroundColor = "#000000")]

    public class PepperEngine extends FlxGame
```

What is this doing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's giving the compiler some info on what it's supposed to do. In the [Embed] bracket it's saying that that .ttf file will be loaded and that it's gonna be used as a protected var called junk of type string. It's like when in the Flash IDE you declare something in the library and then you put a linkage class to it so that it can be referenced in an .as file.
The package one is saying that the file is gonna be of a certain width, height and backgroundColor.
In overall, it's just giving info to the compiler so that it can interpret certain things in a certain way.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. They look like function calls, am I correct? Can you call any function or is there a list of compiler functions that are callable from here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [list of the complete metadata tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html)
That you can use with the Mxmlc flex compiler. I'm not sure if you can use this tags with the regular Flash compiler though.